# Replace "true" and "false" in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I replace "true" and "false" in DataGrid to display something else, let's say "online/offline".

I'm getting data from MySQL database using this code:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=xo_game;UID=root;PASSWORD=;");

try
{
    connection.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, player_one, player_two, avaible FROM games", connection);
    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
    dataGridGames.DataContext = ds;
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

I'm beginner in C# pls help :/

Comment: Easiest way would be to use an `IValueCOnverter`

Comment: Yes, he had the same problem, but he was using DataGridView and it's a little bit diffrent. In DataGrid you can't apply the same functions

Comment: @MightyBadaboom thx for suggestion, I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to show the column Available.
You can try using the Case Statement in your query

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection    ("SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=xo_game;UID=root;PASSWORD=;");

   try
   {
   connection.Open();

 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, player_one, player_two,   CASE avaible WHEN 1 THEN 'Available' ELSE 'Not available' END as 'avaible' FROM games", connection);
 MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
 dataGridGames.DataContext = ds;
 }
 catch (MySqlException ex)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
 }
 finally
 {
 connection.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Yes, this is what I want to do

Comment: I'm happy for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM pattern, you need to create a converter (implementing `IValueConverter`) which will take the true/false and display as online/offline.

Internet/SO is full of such examples.

Comment: The MessageBox.Show() indicates that it is winforms.

Comment: @PalleDue: Question is tagged as `wpf`. Also `MessageBox.Show` works for wpf too.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'll give you an upvote for actually reading the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to keep your SQL Command solid, here is how you can use the `IValueConverter` on Column creation:

Subscribe to `DataGrid`'s `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` event as:

```
    private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "avaible")
        {
            var b = (e.Column as DataGridCheckBoxColumn).Binding as Binding;
            b.Converter = new BoolToStringConverter();
            var dgtc = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dgtc.Binding = b;
            e.Column = dgtc;
        }
    }
```